# WPF: How to delay event firing defined in XAML?

Tags: wpf, events

In WPF, you can define an event handler in XAML (e.g. ComboBox's SelectionChanged), which is great. However, the problem I oftern run into is that the event is fired too early. It is wired up when the control is just created. As a result, if another control below that code is referenced in the event handler, you would get null exception. I ended up with a lot of null checks in my event handler which would be unnecessary otherwise. I would like to have all events hooked up after all controls are created (e.g. OnInitialized). Is there a way to do it? Or did I miss something here?

Comment: can you post your code? do you bind SelectedItem to anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to define these event handlers in code-behind yourself, after the `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor. Of course this will not be XAML anymore, but it's the only way to ensure that all controls your handlers may reference have been already created.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have most of the event handlers defined this way. However, somehow I feel it's a little cleaner to let those handlers declared in XAML (like in WinForm designer). I want to make it consistent, so I need to choose one way or the other for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your main control's [IsLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded.aspx) property at the beginning of your event handler, and return if it's false. So when it is true you'll be confident that everything is created and ready for interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on IsLoaded property.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I can't rely on those events to setup correctly on startup, and I need to call the event handle explicitly.